# ReadProcessMemory once to scan a string

Tags: python, memory

I'm new on Python and im trying to scan my program for a specific string with ReadProcessMemory but its very very slow. I read one int at a time and i don't know how i can make it faster. How can call ReadProcessMemoryonce and then check for my string?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
start = 0
end =   0x7ffffff
batch_size = 0x100000

buff = c.create_string_buffer(batch_size)
bufferSize = (c.sizeof(buff))
bytesRead = c.c_ulonglong()

string = c.create_string_buffer(255)
stringSize = (c.sizeof(string))

for c_adress in range(start,end,batch_size):

    result = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle,c.c_void_p(c_adress), buff, 
                            bufferSize, None)

    if result: # Save adress
        for i in range(start, batch_size - stringSize):
            print('im stuck here')

    #if 'Test text' in extract(buff.value):

e = GetLastError()
CloseHandle(processHandle)
```

Comment: Just read larger blocks of e. g. 1 MB. You only have to ensure that the blocks overlap by the number of bytes of the search term (here: "Test text").

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you a lot for your answer. Yes i tried to read larger blocs of 8Mb. But i don't know how to ensure that the blocks overlab the number of bytes of the search term :( I tried lot of things but i'm stuck

Comment: In the "range" call to iterate the addresses just add a step argument of block size minus search term size.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I updated my code and im still stuck. I check all stackoverlow messages about memory. I can't figured out how to do it. Sorry :( Is it possible to help me? Thank you <3

Comment: The step of the inner for-loop should be used in the outer for-loop, the inner for-loop is unnecessary and should be replaced either by the previous "in" check or a "find" method call.